# If a square matrix has no eigenvectors, then it is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

If a square matrix $A$ has no eigenvectors, then $A$ is invertible?

I'm trying to prove that the answer is yes. My try:

If $A$ has no eigenvectors, then

$$\text{ker}(A-\lambda I) = \{0\}$$
for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}.$ So, $(A-\lambda I)$ is invertible.

After that, I can't proceed.

Comment: In particular, what happens when $\lambda=0$? What does that tell you about $A$?

Comment: In particular, for $\lambda=0$, A is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A square matrix $A$ is not invertible iff, for two distinct vectors $x$ and $y$, the equation $Ax = Ay$ holds. But then $Ax=Ay; x \not = y;$ $\implies A(x-y)=0 \implies$ $x-y$ is an eigenvector of $A$ $\implies$ $A$ has an eigenvector [namely $x-y$, corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$].

So if $A$ is not invertible then it has an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ square matrix over a field $F$ and let $K$ be the algebraic closure of $F$. If $A$ has no eigenvectors in $F^n$, then $A$ has no eigenvalues in $F$. In particular, 0 is not an eigenalue of $A.$ But the determinant of $A$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $A$ in $K$ and thus cannot be 0. So $A$ is invertible over $F$.